# Insert data to the postgres database from a jsp

Tags: jsp, postgresql

Hey i want to insert 5 text field say ID, NAme, TIME, latitude, Longitude in a jsp. The user enters the details in the text field and i give a submit button. Onclicking the submit i need to send all the data entered by the user to the database which has a table say sample. 
How do i do?

This is my example.jsp

```
<label> Name </label > <input type="text" name="name" id="test1" > </input>
<label> ID </label > <input type="text" name="id" id="test2" > </input>
<label> Time </label > <input type="text" name="time" id="test3" > </input>
<label> Latitude </label > <input type="text" name="latitude" id="test4" > </input>
<label> Longitude </label > <input type="text" name="longitude" id="test5" > </input>
<input type= " button" id="test6" value="submit" > </input>
```

Comment: Do you know servlet? see this [servlet info page to get start with](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: yea i know but how do i connect with database?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PostgreSQL JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) by including the JAR file as a referenced library in your  app.